# Find similarities between string in SYBASE SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, sybase

I have two strings. I would like to know the upto how many characters are similar in both the strings.

E.x: lets say 'xyzabc', 'xyzadh'. I would like to know if there is a function that can give the index at which the similarity is breaking. In this case it would be 4 because upto 'xyza' the strings are same. If the strings are 'xyzabc', 'xymabc' then the result should be 2.

I would like to use it as `select func('xyzabc', 'xyzwer');` to get the required answer. Kinldy let me know if there is a function existing in SQL.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: What version of Sybase are you using?  The answer to your question is that you need regular expressions . . . but they are not in all versions of the product.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am not sure about the version. I will check and let you know. Meanwhile, if we assume that my version supports regular expressions, then what could be the method to check the similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with regular expressions.  Here is the idea.  You would use regexp_substr().  The regular expression would, in your example, be 'xyzwer|xyzwe|xyzw|xyz|xy|x'.  You would then measure the length of the matching substring.  In other words, you need to convert one of the strings to a regular expression.

An alternative is to use a giant case statement:

```
 (case when left(str1, 10) = left(str2, 10) then 10
       when left(str1, 9) = left(str2, 9) then 9
       ...
       when left(str1, 1) = left(str2, 1) then 1
       else 0
   end)
```

This assumes that 10 is the longest string.